# How to print a dynamic string with precedence - one liner

Tags: bash, sed, text-formatting, echo

So I want to construct a command that would print a dynamic string with precedence.

I have variables:

```
a=first
b=second/third/fourth/...
```

I want to run `sed` command on `b`

```
sed  -e 's/\//_/g'
```

and I get

```
second_third_fourth_
```

and then I want to print as `a/${b}` so it becomes `

```
first/second_third_fourth_
```

Something like this:

```
echo first/(second/third/fourth... | sed  -e 's/\//_/g' )
```

I am new to bash scripting and need to do this for a CI environment.

Comment: What shell are you using? What is this `var a=first`? What is `var`?

Comment: I used the var keyword so that it would be easy to understand. Actually my CI environment already has the two variables pre declared that I have to use.
Thanks

Comment: Just change the `g` to `2g` in the gnu sed command you were using and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can simply do:

```
$ echo "$a/$(sed  -e 's/\//_/g'<<<"$b")"
first/second_third_fourth_...
```

The `<<<` is a herestring and it's just a quick (but non-portable; bash supports this but many other shells do not) way of passing a variable as input to a program.

Alternatively:

```
$ echo "$a/$(tr '/' '_'<<<"$b")"
first/second_third_fourth_...
```

Answer (score 6):

```
]# echo $a $b
first sec/th/for/

]# echo $a/${b//\//_}
first/sec_th_for_
```

---

To find the place in man bash: `/Param<Enter>nnnnn` to get case-sensitively to ***Parameter Expansion*** paragraph.

Comment: Right but quote it: `echo "$a/${b//\//_}"`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 4):

`bash`:

```
echo "$a/${b//\//_}"
```

---

`zsh`:

```
echo $a/${b:gs;/;_}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: Does the zsh version **really** need to be unquoted? What necessary functionality does removing the quotes provide?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $b | sed -e 's/\//_/g' | xargs -i echo $a/{}
```

Comment: Is there some typo ?

Comment: @Dibyanshu if you get an error message, you need to tell us what it is. There is no typo I can see here, but we can't help you since you don't tell us what went wrong when you tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in `bash`:

```
# NOT var x=...
a=first
b="second/third/fourth/"

# use another separator to avoid escaping backlashes, in this case a semicolon
echo "$a/$(echo "$b" | sed 's;/;_;g')"
```

Output:

```
first/second_third_fourth_
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$a/$b"  | sed 's:/:_:2g'
```

Uses GNU sed. This changes all the slashes to underscore except the first.

It is equivalent to the below Posix sed, to be read as :"till you are able to change the 2nd slash to an underscore, keep repeating."

```
sed -e ':a'   -e 's:/:_:2'     -e 'ta'
```